# Nagios plugin 1.4.3 compilation failed on Solaris 9

Tags: openssl, makefile, solaris, nagios

System information:

```
uname -m = sun4us
uname -r = 5.9
uname -s = SunOS
uname -v = Generic_122300-39
OpenSSL 0.9.8 05 Jul 2005
```

/usr/bin/uname -p = sparc

I have tried two choices of ssl usage but still it is failed.

```
./configure -with-ssl=/usr/sfw/ -with-ssl-lib=/usr/sfw/lib/
```

I have also tried

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

when I ran make command got the following issue

```
gcc -o check_icmp check_icmp.o  -L/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/tmp/.ptmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.3/plugins-root -lnsl -lresolv ../intl/libintl.a /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so -lgen -lsocket -lssl -lcrypto -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/ssl/lib
make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target `pst3'
Current working directory /tmp/.ptmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.3/plugins-root
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
Current working directory /tmp/.ptmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.3
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all'
```

any suggestions on this error?

Comment: Sun OS 5.9 corresponds to Solaris 9. Not Solaris 2.9.

Comment: Be sure to use `gmake` (GNU's make) rather than Sun's make. That is a general recommendation when you take stuff from Internet (probably originally developed on Linux) and then try to compile on Solaris. You are on Solaris 9. Really ??  Are you aware how old that is? Nowadays GNU make for Solaris is delivered by Oracle itself but for that old a version of Solaris you'll have to find another way to get hold of GNU make.

Comment: can you pleae help by pointing where can I get this GNU make for Sun OS 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found the solution by researching on the various nagios mail chains. Most of the time the fix was found with in the daily snapshots of nagios-plugins. I have selected next near by versions, here I fixed it by downloading nagios-plugin1.4.9. The next version 1.5 is supporting 64 that is giving issue.