# Make failed nagios-plugins-1.4.3 and 1.4.9 on SunOS 9

Tags: plugins, makefile, nagios, sunos

Here I have tried two versions of plugin compilation here: 1.4.3 and 1.4.9 the new issue with make, it is saying the following

Using nagios-plugin-1.4.3

```
source='check_ldap.c' object='check_ldap.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=gcc /bin/bash ../depcomp \
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/nagios/share/locale\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I.. -I../lib -I../intl -I/usr/include/ldap  -I/usr/local/ssl/include   -I/usr/local/ssl/include -Wall -g -O2 -c check_ldap.c
check_ldap.c: In function `main':
check_ldap.c:105: warning: implicit declaration of function `ldap_init'
check_ldap.c:105: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
check_ldap.c:171: warning: implicit declaration of function `ldap_bind_s'
check_ldap.c:179: warning: implicit declaration of function `ldap_search_s'
check_ldap.c:187: warning: implicit declaration of function `ldap_unbind'
/bin/bash ../libtool --mode=link --tag=CC gcc -Wall -g -O2   -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L. -R/usr/local/ssl/lib -o check_ldap  check_ldap.o netutils.o utils.o ../lib/libnagiosplug.a ../lib/libcoreutils.a  -lnsl -lsocket -lresolv -lldap -llber ../intl/libintl.a -liconv -lgen -lsocket  -lssl -lcrypto
gcc -Wall -g -O2 -o check_ldap check_ldap.o netutils.o utils.o  -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/tmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.3/plugins ../lib/libnagiosplug.a ../lib/libcoreutils.a /usr/local/lib/libldap.so -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/openwin/lib -L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib -lnet /usr/local/lib/libsasl2.so -ldl -lnsl -lresolv /usr/local/lib/liblber.so ../intl/libintl.a /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so -lgen -lsocket -lssl -lcrypto -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/ssl/lib
/usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.6/bin/ld: cannot find -lnet
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `check_ldap'
Current working directory /tmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.3/plugins
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
Current working directory /tmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.3/plugins
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
Current working directory /tmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.3
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all'
```

Using nagios-plugins-1.4.9

```
    source='check_ldap.c' object='check_ldap.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=gcc /bin/bash ../build-aux/depcomp \
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/nagios/share/locale\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I.. -I../lib -I../gl -I../intl -I/usr/include/ldap  -I/usr/local/ssl/include   -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/ssl/include  -g -O2 -c check_ldap.c
check_ldap.c: In function `main':
check_ldap.c:118: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L. -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -o check_ldap  check_ldap.o netutils.o utils.o ../lib/libnagiosplug.a ../gl/libgnu.a  -lnsl -lsocket -lresolv -lldap -llber -lsocket
gcc -g -O2 -o check_ldap check_ldap.o netutils.o utils.o  -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/tmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.9/plugins ../lib/libnagiosplug.a ../gl/libgnu.a /usr/local/lib/libldap.so -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/openwin/lib -L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib -lgen -lnet /usr/local/lib/libsasl2.so -ldl -lnsl -lresolv -lssl -lcrypto /usr/local/lib/liblber.so -lsocket -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.6/bin/ld: cannot find -lnet
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `check_ldap'
Current working directory /tmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.9/plugins
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
Current working directory /tmp/nagios-plugins-1.4.9
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all'
```

I sure some libraries missing on this SunOS. Not really sure what it is?

Comment: The error is `/usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.6/bin/ld: cannot find -lnet` which means it can't find the `libnet` library. You need to find out what library that is exactly and install it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nagios plugin 1.4.3 compilation failed on Solaris 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083285/nagios-plugin-1-4-3-compilation-failed-on-solaris-9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot  for your comment Etan,
I have followed the Etan comment here. Searched for the libnet package in the google. found at the following link:

[libnet download link](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/libnet-1.1.1-sol9-sparc-local.gz.1004872-0.html)

The package file copied to the impacting Solaris 9 box, and extracted with gunzip then, ran the following command

```
pckadd -d libnet-1.1.1-sol9-sparc-local
```

Now the issue of lnet gone away! Hope this will help other users who encounter this kind of issues.

Cheers